# Nested array or nested dictionary?

Tags: nsmutablearray, nested, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I want to store STUDENTS marks & comments based on SUBJECTS.

```
NSArray *students = @[@"Johns",@"James",@"Michelle",nil];
NSArray *subjects = @[@"Maths",@"Science",@"History",nil];

NSArray *marks = @[@"80",@"60",@"86",nil];
NSArray *comments = @[@"Very Good",@"Moderate",@"Excellent",nil];
```

Basically, each subject have mark and comments respectively. AND each student has 3 subjects. AND each class has 3 students. How do I nested them together? My brain was stuck!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Student and Class class. Subject can be depicted by NSDictionary with two Key-Pair values (one for Marks and one for comments). Student can have an instance var of type NSArray (this will be an array of Subject dictionaries). Class can have an instance variable of type NSArray (this will be an array of Student objects)

Class.h

```
@interface Class : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *students;

@end
```

Class.m

```
-(id)initWithStudents:(NSMutableArray *)newStudents{
    if(self = [super init]) {
        self. students = newStudents
    }
    return self;
}
```

Student.h

```
@interface Student : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *subjects;

@end
```

Student.m

```
-(id)initWithStudents:(NSMutableArray *)newSubjects{
    if(self = [super init]) {
        self.subjects = newSubjects
    }
    return self;
}
```

Create your Subjects, Student and Class objects as follows:

```
NSMutableDictionary *subject1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[@"80", @"Very Good"] forKeys:@[@"Marks", @"Comments"]];
NSMutableDictionary *subject2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[@"70", @"Good"] forKeys:@[@"Marks", @"Comments"]];
NSMutableDictionary *subject3 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[@"40", @"Poor"] forKeys:@[@"Marks", @"Comments"]];
Student *student1 = [[Student alloc] initWithSubjects:@[subject1, subject2, subject3]];

//Create student2 and student 3 in similar fashion.

Class *class1 = [[Class alloc] initWithStudents:@[srudent1, student2, student3]];
```